# Record video using screenrecord error

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to use the adb shell screenrecord functionality on my S4 which is running 4.4. I keep getting this error
ERROR: unable to configure codec (err=-2147483648)
WARNING: failed at 1080x1920, retrying at 720x1280

Yes the video eventually gets recorded in the lower resolution. How can I record it in the highest resolution possible (even if you can suggest another method)?

Thank you

Comment: Android Studio provide built in functionality to record screen.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately I am using eclipse